# How to call inner class of fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inner-classes

I have one inner class in fragment  from main activity how to  call inner class method in android.   In inner class some Async task is there so I want to call I don't want to make again copy that code in my main activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339841/android-implement-inner-class-in-outer-class-callback-from-inner-class-and-out
Haven't you tried this?

Comment: You will need to improve your question, including posting your existing code if you expect people to help you.